# Client-Side Rendering: How to leverage server/client side templates?

Tags: erb, template-engine, mustache

I'm currently implementing a ruby/sinatra application using erb as the rendering engine using client-side rendering using handlebars/mustache templates as well. I'm implementing a certain list view in which the list elements will be rendered using the client side solution when javascript is present and fallback to server side when not (targeting crawlers this way). But I'm left with the folliowing issue: I basically have two templates written in two different markups which produce the same html. I'd love to "write once, run everywhere". How are other projects leveraging this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to be using your favorite templating flavor on the server-side but using some other templating engine for the cases where the template is going to be shared on the client side. So, I'm using erb most of the time, the rest of the time using [poirot](https://github.com/olivernn/poirot) (for Rails). This integrates Mustache templates on action pack, which handles multiple templating engines anyway. Poirot comes ready with helpers to write the templates on the document and also client side rendering libraries. It also integrates handlebars and hogan templates, which are mustache extensions.

As for Sinatra, I try using the same approach using erb and https://github.com/defunkt/mustache , but the nice integration from poirot on rails has to be done by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [sinatra-mustache](https://github.com/beatrichartz/sinatra-mustache) with Sinatra, and it works great. I have not used it for both client and server side templating from the same template files, but you should be able to do that as well.

Comment: is it compatible with other templating engines? I'd only want to write my prototype-templates in it, other stuff like layouting I'd prefer doing it using the erb/helper rails/sinatra mechanism.